# mysql delete rows keeping the last 5 for the each user_id

Tags: mysql

I have a mysql table ("c5_imgs") with the columns "user_id" (varchar) and "date" (timestamp). The amount of data in this particular table grew much more than I was initially expecting, and now I'm trying to delete all of the records for each user_id except the most recent 5.

I can get the rows I want to delete, for a given user_id:

```
select *
FROM c5_imgs i
where 
    date < (
        select date 
        from c5_imgs i2 
        where i.user_id = i2.user_id 
        order by i2.date desc
        limit 4,1
    )
and user_id = 'xxx'
```

but I'm having problems deleting these rows:

```
delete
FROM c5_imgs
where 
    date < (
        select date 
        from c5_imgs i2 
        where 'xxx' = i2.user_id 
        order by i2.date desc
        limit 4,1
    )
and user_id = 'xxx'

#1093 - You can't specify target table 'c5_imgs' for update in FROM clause
```

and i want to make a generic query for all the user_id, not just for one at a time... any help would be appreciated, thanks.

**Edit**: chetan's answer helped me with the deletion for one of the user_id's but I'm looking for a more generic solution for all the user_id's.

**Edit2**: the query i ended up using was based on Christian's answer:

```
delete aa.* 
from c5_imgs aa,
(
select distinct c.user_id as user_id,
    (select x.date 
    from c5_imgs as x
    where x.user_id = c.user_id
    order by x.date desc
    limit 4,1) as date
from c5_imgs as c
) bb
where aa.user_id = bb.user_id and aa.date < bb.date
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it in three steps:

[First](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ee611/1/0)

```
create table aux
select distinct c.user_id as user_id,
    (select x.date 
    from c5_imgs as x
    where x.user_id = c.user_id
    order by x.date desc
    limit 4,1) as date
from c5_imgs as c;
```

Second

```
delete c5_imgs
from c5_imgs as c
inner join aux as a on a.user_id = c.user_id
where  c.date < a.date;
```

Third

```
drop table aux;
```

If working with large tables, you could create indexes on the columns of aux table to speed up  the delete action.

```
CREATE INDEX aux_idx1 ON aux(user_id);
CREATE INDEX aux_idx2 ON aux(date);
```

Note that you could simplify and improve speed of first step if you have a users table from which you can get the distinct user ids.

This does not guarantee keeping exactly 5 most recent images. In cases where the date is the exact same for more than one image in the 5th and next positions, this will not work as required.

Comment: no, that would not work, at least not for all the the user_ids at the same time. Your first table should have all user_id's and either the 5th result for every user id, or the first 5.

Comment: thanks, that did it. I ended up just using a delete, instead of creating the intermediary table. I will edit my post to show the query I used.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that using join. for example

```
delete a.*
FROM c5_imgs a, (
        select date 
        from c5_imgs
        where 'xxx' = user_id 
        order by date desc
        limit 4,1
    ) b
where 
    a.date < b.date
and a.user_id = 'xxx';
```

I haven't run this query, but it should work. Work around if necessary.

Comment: thanks, that solved a part of my problem :), but i need a more generic query to do the same for all the user_id's